# Match capitalise and lower case

Tags: scala, match, sequence, contains

I’m trying to match the Scala string sequence with .contains(“pear”). I’m able to match pear, but is there any other way to match no matter capital or lower case of the “Pear” other than toLowerCase first or using regex? This is what I did so far.

```
val fruits = Seq("apple", "PEAR")
fruits.map(_.toLowerCase).contains("pear")

Boolean = true
```

Comment: `fruits.exists(_.equalsIgnoreCase("pear"))`

Comment: there are probably tens of different ways. But WHY:\

Answer (score 1):

As [sinanspd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3628806/sinanspd) said

```
fruits.exists(_.equalsIgnoreCase("pear"))
```

This is better since rather than converting every element of `fruits` to lowercase, it only converts as many characters as needed to reject or match an element.